# UINavigationBar Disappears using UISearchBar and SearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios4, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Here is my scenario:

(1)  I have a TabBarController with the following:

```
      (A)  Navigation Controller (rootviewcontroller is a uitableviewcontroller) = Tab 0

      (B)  UIViewController = Tab 1
```

(2)  The Navigation Controller is using a UISearchBar along with UISearchDisplayController

(3)  I click into and enter a search into the search bar and then hit "Search" on the keyboard to dismiss keyboard, leaving the search results displayed.

(4)  Then I click into Tab #1.

(5)  Then I "Simulate Memory Warning"

(6).  Click back to Tab #0

(7).  Hit "Cancel" on the UiSearchBar

(8)  VOILA!  Navigation Bar is gone.  Missing.  Not there.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```